# TASM last letter and length of line

Tags: assembly, dos, tasm, 16-bit

I am trying to make a TASM program that can take a line from a file, check if it's more then 5 symbols long, check whether it's a palindrome and then output whether or not it is a palindrome. My program so far is able to tell when it needs to output help, read a file and output the answer. My problems are twofold:

1) How do you point to the last letter of a line in TASM? My palindrome checker works by comparing the first and last letters, checking if they're the same, if so then move up by 1 and down by 1, check those 2 etc. If any two are not the same, it's not a palindrome.

2) How do you check to make sure the line in question is at least 6 letters/numbers long?

For reference, here's the code so far:

```
.model small
.stack 100H
.data

about       db 'Programa iesko palindromu nuskaitytoje eiluteje arba faile.',13,10,9,'2uzdasm.exe [/?] destinationFile [ - | sourceFile1 [sourceFile2] [...] ]',13,10,13,10,9,'/? - pagalba',13,10,'$'

err_source      db 'Source failo nepavyko atidaryti skaitymui',13,10,'$'
err_destination     db 'Destination failo nepavyko atidaryti rasymui',13,10,'$'

sourceF     db 12 dup (0)
sourceFHandle   dw ?

destF       db 12 dup (0)
destFHandle     dw ?

buffer      db 2000 dup (?)
simbolis    db ?

palindromas db 'Tai yra palindromas',13,10,'$'
nepalindromas db 'Tai nera palindromas',13,10,'$'

.code

START:
mov ax, @data
mov es, ax

mov si, 81h

call space_skip

    mov al, byte ptr ds:[si]    ; nuskaityt simboli
    cmp al, 13          ; ner parametru, tai tada
    jne _1
    jmp help            ; pagalba

_1:

    ;; ar /? yra
    mov ax, word ptr ds:[si]
    cmp ax, 3F2Fh           ; jei nuskaityta "/?" - 3F = '?'; 2F = '/'
    jne _2
    jmp help                    ; rastas "/?", vadinasi reikia isvesti pagalba


_2:

    ;; destination failo pavadinimas
    lea di, destF
    call    read_filename       ; perkelti is parametro i eilute
    cmp byte ptr es:[destF], '$' ; jei nieko nenuskaite
    jne _3
    jmp help

_3:

    ;; source failo pavadinimas
    lea di, sourceF
    call    read_filename       ; perkelti is parametro i eilute

    push    ds
    push    si

    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    ;; rasymui
    mov dx, offset destF    ; ikelti i dx destF - failo pavadinima
    mov ah, 3ch         ; isvalo/sukuria faila - komandos kodas
    mov cx, 0           ; normal - no attributes
    int 21h         ; INT 21h / AH= 3Ch - create or truncate file.
                ;   Jei nebus isvalytas - tai perrasines senaji,
                ;   t.y. jei pries tai buves failas ilgesnis - like simboliai isliks.
    jnc _4          ; CF set on error AX = error code.
    jmp err_dest

_4:
    mov ah, 3dh         ; atidaro faila - komandos kodas
    mov al, 1           ; rasymui
    int 21h         ; INT 21h / AH= 3Dh - open existing file.
    jnc _5          ; CF set on error AX = error code.
    jmp err_dest

_5:
    mov destFHandle, ax     ; issaugom handle

    jmp startConverting

readSourceFile:
    pop si
    pop ds

    ;; source failo pavadinimas
    lea di, sourceF
    call    read_filename       ; perkelti is parametro i eilute

    push    ds
    push    si

    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    cmp byte ptr ds:[sourceF], '$' ; jei nieko nenuskaite
    jne startConverting
    jmp closeF

startConverting:
    ;; atidarom
    cmp byte ptr ds:[sourceF], '$' ; jei nieko nenuskaite
    jne source_from_file

    mov sourceFHandle, 0
    jmp skaitom

source_from_file:
    mov dx, offset sourceF  ; failo pavadinimas
    mov ah, 3dh                 ; atidaro faila - komandos kodas
    mov al, 0                   ; 0 - reading, 1-writing, 2-abu
    int 21h         ; INT 21h / AH= 3Dh - open existing file
    jc  err_sourc       ; CF set on error AX = error code.
    mov sourceFHandle, ax   ; issaugojam filehandle

skaitom:
    mov bx, sourceFHandle
    mov dx, offset buffer       ; address of buffer in dx
    mov cx, 20              ; kiek baitu nuskaitysim
    mov ah, 3fh             ; function 3Fh - read from file
    int 21h

    mov cx, ax              ; bytes actually read
    cmp ax, 0           ; jei nenuskaite
    jne _6          ; tai ne pabaiga

    mov bx, sourceFHandle   ; pabaiga skaitomo failo
    mov ah, 3eh         ; uzdaryti
    int 21h
    jmp readSourceFile      ; atidaryti kita skaitoma faila, jei yra

_6:
    mov si, offset buffer   ; skaitoma is cia
    mov bx, destFHandle     ; rasoma i cia

    cmp sourceFHandle, 0
    jne _7
    cmp byte ptr ds:[si], 13
    je  closeF

_7:
    push    cx          ; save big loop CX

atrenka:
    lodsb               ; Load byte at address DS:(E)SI into AL
    push    cx          ; pasidedam cx
    call    palloop
    mov ah, 40h         ; INT 21h / AH= 40h - write to file
    int 21h
    pop cx
    jc  help            ; CF set on error; AX = error code.
    loop    atrenka

    pop cx
    loop    skaitom

help:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    mov dx, offset about         
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h

    jmp _end

closeF:
    ;; uzdaryti dest
    mov ah, 3eh         ; uzdaryti
    mov bx, destFHandle
    int 21h

_end:
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h  

err_sourc:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    mov dx, offset err_source        
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h

    mov dx, offset sourceF
    int 21h

    mov ax, 4c01h
    int 21h  

err_dest:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    mov dx, offset err_destination         
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h

    mov dx, offset destF
    int 21h

    mov ax, 4c02h
    int 21h  

space_skip PROC near

space_skip_loop:
    cmp byte ptr ds:[si], ' '
    jne space_skip_end
    inc si
    jmp space_skip_loop
    space_skip_end:
    ret

    space_skip ENDP

    read_filename PROC near

    push    ax
    call    space_skip

read_filename_start:
    cmp byte ptr ds:[si], 13    ; jei nera parametru
    je  read_filename_end   ; tai taip, tai baigtas failo vedimas
    cmp byte ptr ds:[si], ' '   ; jei tarpas
    jne read_filename_next  ; tai praleisti visus tarpus, ir sokti prie kito parametro
    read_filename_end:
    mov al, '$'         ; irasyti '$' gale
    stosb                           ; Store AL at address ES:(E)DI, di = di + 1
    pop ax
    ret
    read_filename_next:
    lodsb               ; uzkrauna kita simboli
    stosb                           ; Store AL at address ES:(E)DI, di = di + 1
    jmp read_filename_start

    read_filename ENDP

palloop PROC near
    mov     al, [si]
    ;mov        [di], al
    cmp     al, [di]
    jne     notpal
    inc     si
    dec     di
    cmp     si, di
    jl      palloop
    jmp     ispal

notpal:
    lea dx, nepalindromas
    mov cx, 20
    ret

ispal:
    lea dx, palindromas
    mov cx, 20
    ret

    palloop ENDP

    end START
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess,

```
mov bx, sourceFHandle
mov dx, offset buffer   ; address of buffer in dx
mov cx, 20              ; kiek baitu nuskaitysim
mov ah, 3fh             ; function 3Fh - read from file
int 21h
```

will get you in trouble. Try to create a C program with `fread(buffer,1,20,sourceFHandle)` and you will see, that the organization of the buffer is rather difficult (what to do with handled data? Overflow?).

I suggest to read a line and just a line("`fgets`"). A line can end with the character 0x0D (Carriage Return = CR) or 0x0Ah (Line Feed = LF) or EOF (End of file). MS-DOS uses for a new line typically the combination of both (CRLF). There is no function in MS-DOS to read a line until one of that delimiters, so you have to read character by character and compare it with the break condition. Since the handle has its own buffer and manages to get a block of data from the disk, this is not a great performance issue.

Example:

```
...
read_line PROC
    lea di, buffer
    dec di

    @@0:                        ; Read until CR or LF
    inc di
    mov ah, 3Fh                 ; READ FROM FILE OR DEVICE
    mov bx, sourceFHandle       ; File handle
    mov dx, di                  ; Buffer for data
    mov cx, 1                   ; Read one character
    int 21h                     ; Call MS-DOS
    jc @@done                   ; Error
    test ax, ax                 ; EOF
    je @@done

    mov al, [di]                ; Fetched character
    cmp al, 0Dh                 ; CR?
    je @@1                      ; Yes: break
    cmp al, 0Ah                 ; LF?
    jne @@0                     ; No: loop

    @@1:                        ; Read until NOT CR or LF (skip empty lines)

    mov ah, 3Fh                 ; READ FROM FILE OR DEVICE
    mov bx, sourceFHandle       ; File handle
    mov dx, di                  ; Buffer for data
    mov cx, 1                   ; Read one character
    int 21h                     ; Call MS-DOS
    jc @@done                   ; Error
    test ax, ax                 ; EOF
    je @@done

    mov al, [di]                ; Fetched character
    cmp al, 0Dh                 ; CR?
    je @@1                      ; Yes: loop
    cmp al, 0Ah                 ; LF?
    je @@1                      ; Yes: loop

    ; Adjust file pointer, so that it points to the beginning of the next line

    mov ah, 42h                 ; LSEEK - SET CURRENT FILE POSITION
    mov al, 1                   ; Move from current file position
    mov bx, sourceFHandle       ; File handle
    mov dx, -1                  ; Move by CX:DX = -1 bytes
    mov cx, dx                  ; CX:DX = FFFF:FFFF
    int 21h                     ; Call MS-DOS

    @@done:
    test ax, ax                 ; AX == 0 && DI == &buffer[0] => EOF
    jne @@2
    cmp di, OFFSET buffer
    @@2:
    mov byte ptr [di], '$'
    ret                         ; DI: pointer to '$'. ZF==1: EOF.
read_line ENDP
...
```

Since `DI` points to the `$`-delimiter of the line, you can calculate the length of the string by subtracting the offset of buffer (e.g. `sub di, OFFSET buffer`). Decrementing `DI` by one brings you to the last letter.

BTW: It's easier for outsiders to help when you program more structured: more procedures, less jumps.